# Passing Variable from python using flask framework to HTML in render template isn't working?

Tags: python, html, function, variables, flask

**app.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import random

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def index():
    number = random.randint(0, 10)
    return render_template("index.html", value='number')
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Random Number</title>
</head>

<body>
    Your random number is {{ value }}.
</body>

</html>
```

**Webpage Result**

Your random number is number.

*It isnt replacing the number with actual number. Kindly help!*

> BTW i am coding this in PyCharm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
return render_template("index.html", value='number')
```

with

```
return render_template("index.html", value=number)
```

You need to send variable not string.
If you use value='number', value is a string which is 'number' or anything inside the quotes. For example if you set value='another number', then you will see 'Your random number is another number.'

If you want to use the value of 'number' variable use it without quotes. This will ensure you are passing the value of the number variable and not a string.